# How to install Ubuntu on Odys Winbook 14 - USB booting via uefi not working

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I couldn't figure out yet how to install Ubuntu on an [Odys Winbook 14](https://www.conrad.de/de/odys-356-cm-14-zoll-notebook-intel-celeron-4-gb-64-gb-ssd-intel-hd-graphics-515-windows-10-home-dunkel-grau-1606298.html?customer-switch).

Stats:

```
Intel® Celeron® Quad Core Processor with up to 4x 2,2 GHz Burstspeed
35,56 cm (14") 16:9 Full-HD IPS Display (1.920x1.080 pixel)
Windows 10 Home Operating System (64-bit)
64 GB Internal Flash HDD, 4 GB DDR III RAM
1x USB 2.0, 1x USB 3.0, Mini HDMI, Micro-SD slot, M.2 SSD slot, headphone jack
Bluetooth 4.0, supports WiFi 801.11 b/g/n/ac Fingerprint-Scanner

Bios Mode: UEFI
```

I tried a bootable usb-stick (via rufus) with image Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64 on it. The stick works, tested it before somewhere else. Later I want to use Gnome Megacity.

But I can’t seem to boot from the stick on the Winbook 14. How can I install it?

Here is [a thread](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/installation-von-ubuntu-auf-sd-karte-eines-not/) who supposedly made it work:

> I have now managed to install Ubuntu (Lubuntu). There are many descriptions to make a USB stick bootable. I have done it with Rufus, because you still have to copy the 32-bit UEFI file named by Sprottenwels into the folder UEFI / boot. After that start (in the UEFI menu secureboot must be disabled, you can get into this menu by pressing the Escape key, while the ODYS icon appears at startup) and go into UEFI mode and use the arrow keys to navigate to the Boot tab and select your stick. Then the menu of the live session appears. Try it out and install ubuntu afterwards. I did not succeed to install it on an external SD card, but to a USB stick (in the query how to install, select the bottom menu item and create an EFI system partition and a file system with mount point or of course you can also I have Windows flattened With Kernel 4.13 (Ubuntu 17.10) runs the internal WiFi module A patched ISO can be found if you googled to Thinbook github, which offers a patched ISO for Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate and Xubuntu.This ISO also runs the internal sound and the internal Bluetooth module as well as the camera.Ubuntu is a bit heavy because it has a high RAM requirement.I'm totally happy.With down controlled display, the calculator offers me 10- 11 hours running time, video about 8 hours.

I also loaded [this 32-bit UEFI bootfile](https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asut/bootia32.efi) into EFI/BOOT folder. But when selecting to boot from the usb device ... save and exit ... I get a black display. What else can I to do?

I've set 'Secure Boot' to disabled as suggested in some threads. And I also can't find and then change 'Boot Mode' to 'UEFI' and 'Launch CSM' to "enable" as suggested in other threads. I also set `UEFI: VendorCoProducer` (which I think is my usb device) to boot option #1:

[image: Picture: BIOS Main]
[image: Picture: BIOS Advanced]
[image: Picture: BIOS Security]
[image: Picture: BIOS Boot]

When I then choose the UEFI: USB Device → Save & Exit → I get a black screen and only see the command prompt